# What are the differences between Python Dictionaries vs Javascript Objects?

Tags: javascript, python, object, dictionary

I'm new to Python and I was reading about Dictionaries. And from my previous experience with languages like Javascript, they seemed like objects to me. Dictionaries can store lists and share many similaraties to objects in Javascript.

ex python code:

```
menu = {}
menu['Chicken Alfredo'] = 14.50
menu['Italian Pasta'] = 15.89
menu['Shrimp Soup'] = 12.43
menu['Persian Rice'] = 21.99
```

ex javascript code:

```
var menu = new Object();
menu['Chicken Alfredo'] = 14.50;
menu['Italian Pasta'] = 15.89;
menu['Shrimp Soup'] = 12.43;
menu['Persian Rice'] = 21.99;
```

What's the difference here, they both do the same job, but there different concepts?

Comment: You know that you are talking about two different languages, right? What kind of differences you are looking for?

Comment: the python code is also js...

Comment: Javascript allows things like `menu.chicken` as an alias for `menu['chicken']` (IIRC), but python doesn't allow that.  Also, a python dictionary will raise an `KeyError` if a requested item isn't present.  Javascript will return `undefined` (again, IIRC)...

Comment: @dandavis syntactically they are the same, but a dictionary might behave differently than a JS object

Comment: In python dict you can use any immutable type as key(string, int, tuple, frozenset, etc), but in js objects all keys are converted to strings. So, `menu['1']` and `menu[1]` are same thing in js, but not in Python dicts.

Comment: BTW there is a python package that provides attribute-style access for dictionaries. It allows things like `menu.chicken`,  `menu.chicken = 1`, etc. https://github.com/Infinidat/munch

Answer (score 78, accepted):

[From :](http://www.cs.miami.edu/~burt/learning/five-easy-pieces/newwb/arrays_objects_dictionaries.html)

> In Python, dictionaries are a form of mapping type. They can be
>   initialized using a sequence of comma-separated name: value pairs,
>   enclosed in curly braces. They are accessed using array notation
>   involving square braces. The key can be any hashable, including
>   numbers and strings.
>
> In Javascript, a dictionary is the same as an object. It can be
>   initialized using the same syntax as Python. The key can be a number,
>   a string, or an identifier. Because the dictionary is also an object,
>   the elements can be accessed either using array notation, e.g. b[i],
>   or using property notation, e.g. b.i.
>
> Consider an identifier used in an initializer, such as
>
> ```
>  b = {i:j}
> ```
>
> In Python both i and j are evaluated, but in Javascript, only j is evaluated. In Javascript you also have the
>   privilege of writing in the dot notation, using the identifier i.
>   Hence in Python,
>
> ```
>  i='k'
>  j=1
>  b = {i:j}
>  b['k'] # -> 1
> ```
>
> In Javascript,
>
> ```
>  i='k'
>  j=1
>  b = {i:j}
>  b['i'] // -> 1
>  b.i // -> 1
>  // b[i], b['k'] and b.k are not defined
> ```
>
> In Javascript, using the identifier in dot notation is completely identical in all cases to
>   using a string that "looks like" the identifier in array notation.
>   Hence,
>       b = { 'i':1 } ;
>       b['i'] // -> 1 
>       b.i // -> 1  When a number or boolean is used in a dictionary, Javascript will access the element using a string representation of
>   the number or boolean. Not so in Python — a string and a number (or
>   boolean) are different hashables.

If you are interested in differences between both languages, then look at [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786522/how-different-are-the-semantics-between-python-and-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: The `->` operator doesn't exist in Python (second block of code)

Comment: @Jacquot he's just saying that `b['k']` would be a value of `1`

Comment: @tisaconundrum yeah I know, the `-> 1` has been commented out since I commented ; I guess at the time I was just picky, for those who are prompt to copy-paste code to see what it outputs

Answer (score 21):

1. Keys in Python dictionaries must be hashable (e.g. a string, a number, a float), while JavaScript does not have such a requirement.
2. The following is a valid object in JavaScript:

```js
const javascriptObject = { name: 'Alexander Pushkin', year: 1799 }
```

However, it would be invalid as a Python dictionary:

```py
python_dictionary = {name: 'Alexander Pushkin', year: 1799}


# Results in a NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

A quick fix would be to convert the Python dictionary's keys into strings:

```py
my_dictionary = {'name': 'Alexander Pushkin', 'year': 1799}
```

Comment: In Javascript, what type are name and year? Are they typecasted to strings?

Comment: @Zaku string and Number

Answer (score 0):

With given difference write in submitted answers one difference is  missing. That is,Java Script objects are not iterable,but Python dictionaries are. If we looped over a python dictionary and java scripts object we get a TypeError in case of Java Script(code snippet is given below).
for e.g.
in case python dictionary,

```
dict={'Name':'Ram',
      'Occupation': 'Scientist',
      'salary': '50000'
         }
```

if we iterate over dict with for loop,we get following output.

```
for i  in  dict:
    print(i)


>>> Ram
    Occupation
    Salary
```

but in case of java script :

```
dict={Name:'Ram',
      Occupation: 'Scientist',
      salary: '50000'​}

for(i of dict){
  console.log(i)}
>>TypeError dict in not iterable.
```

Comment: At least as of 2022 and testing in Chrome, this is not accurate. If you change it to `i in dict` (you have a typo), it iterates just fine

Comment: Is that a typo `of`?