# What is the difference between a JS object, Python dictionary and a C++ Struct?

Tags: javascript, python, c++

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988172/13491892) explains the differences/similarities between a Python dictionary and a JavaScript object. However I would like to know the differences/similarities between a JS `object` and Python `dict` to a C++ `struct`. 
These 3 datatypes seems to be equivalents to each other in their respective languages, however I would assume that there is more nuance to the applications in which each of them would be used. Otherwise there would be no need for other datastructures such as the C++ `map`.

Comment: Try to add another field to C++ struct programmatically and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no equivalent data type that is built-in to C++.

C++ structs (which are just classes with default public member visibility) have the names and types of their members determined at compile time.  For example, with a C++ struct/class, you **cannot** do these at runtime:

- Ask an object what members it has (reflection)
- Ask an object if it has a member with a specific name
- Look up the object member with a given name
- Create a new member
- Change the type of value stored by an existing member

All of these are possible with JavaScript objects and Python dictionaries, but *none of these* are possible with C++ structs/classes.

About the closest thing you could have in vanilla C++ would be `std::map<std::string, void *>` and then you're having to manually manage memory for each value as well as be able to determine somehow what kind of value is stored.

There are some [variant types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variant_type) that others have written for C++.  For example, [boost's variant type](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html) could work, but you still must supply a list of all of the types you will ever need to use at compile time.  With this kind of value type, you could have an `std::map<std::string, boost::variant<list, of, types, here>>` that would function similarly to a JavaScript object or Python dictionary, but with a restricted set of acceptable types.

Generally, however, you don't need this kind of dynamism in C++, which has other facilities for dealing with this kind of thing.