# Are JavaScript object literals the same thing as Python dictionaries?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary, object-literal

I’ve started using JavaScript recently and have noticed a resemblance between JavaScript object literals and python dictionaries. They are used in similar situations and have similar syntax. So are they basically the same thing but with different names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the differences between Python Dictionaries vs Javascript Objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987485/what-are-the-differences-between-python-dictionaries-vs-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They have the same structures; `key: value`. The key could be an array, integer, object etc. Same goes for the value.

Python:

```
my_python_dictionary = {'name': 'John', age: 5, 123: 'a string'}
one_of_the_values_of_my_python_dictionary = my_python_dictionary['name']
```

JavaScript:

```
let myJavaScriptObjectLiteral = {"name": "John", age: 5, 123: "a string"}
let oneOfTheValuesOfMyJavaScriptObjectLiteral = myJavaScriptObjectLiteral["name"]
```

Answer (score 1):

it is totally not the same thing.
in JS, object literals is a object, so you can combine them with data and function, and you can call the method by dot, just like x.xxx(), and you can deconstruction it with the same symbol {...}, just like other object.

but in python, dict is not a object, you can not use dot, and if you want deconstruction, you must use ** for it, by the way, you can deconstruction turple by *

summarize: their is nothing just like object literals in python...