# Differences between a Python dictionary and JavaScript "dictionary"?

Tags: javascript, python, dictionary

I am learning JavaScript now. I learned in a class that JavaScript dictionaries are objects. The teacher said this in a way that implied that python dictionaries are not. It seems like to me a python dictionary is an instance of the class "dictionary." One implication of this is that in JavaScript `my_dict['key1']` will return the associated `value1`, but so will `my_dict.key1`. In python, `my_dict.key1` will tell you that there is no method `key1` in the class "dictionary." While I know how to use python, my general knowledge of programming is fairly week. My questions are these:

1. what are the differences between Python dictionaries and JavaScript dictionaries
2. What is the implication that "JavasScript dictionaries are objects" vs the corollary "Python dictionaries are NOT objects" (if that is true)?
3. How does this effect how I should think about programing in Python vs JavaScript when using dictionaries?

Comment: This is off-topic in several respects.  It appears that you're asking us to give you a tutorial overview -- knowledge that is available through Python dict tutorials.  You ask multiple questions.  You ask open-ended questions.  Your wording invites opinions.  You ask for resource recommendations.

Comment: "The teacher said this in a way that implied that python dictionaries are not." Well, they are. *Everything* in Python is an object. Indeed, Javascript has primitive types, and python doesnt. In any case, Python dictionaries and Javascript objects are actually used differently, at least, they should be. Python dictionaries are *maps*, equivalent to Javascript [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The equivalent of JS objects are Python instances created from classes, these languages have two different inheritance models

Comment: @Prune I'm leaning to agree with that, but I also think this is a fundamental source of misunderstanding, because they syntaxes are so similar, but there are important differences and conceptually they should be considered very diffeerntly.

Comment: Note, **Javascript doesn't have dictionaries**, those are Javascript Objects. They use a similar *syntax* to Python `dict` literals, but they are conceptually different, although, all objects are inherently mappings from their attributes to their attribute values. But the *direct equivalent* to a Python dictionary is a JS Map

Comment: Sorry if this question is inappropriate. I have read many questions on SO that were similar, and popular such as the one in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786522/how-different-are-the-semantics-between-python-and-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top. I also am really only asking one question "what are the differences between..." as the title says. The other points were to narrow the scope of what could be a broad question to that parts that I am interested in.

Comment: Also, this discussion has been very useful to me in the question that I had, so I wonder if it wouldn't be useful to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, dictionaries are a form of mapping type. They can be initialized using a sequence of comma-separated name: value pairs, enclosed in curly braces. They are accessed using array notation involving square braces. The key can be any hashable, including numbers and strings.

In Javascript, a dictionary is the same as an object. It can be initialized using the same syntax as Python. The key can be a number, a string, or an identifier. Because the dictionary is also an object, the elements can be accessed either using array notation, e.g. b[i], or using property notation, e.g. b.i.

Consider an identifier used in an initializer, such as

```
 b = {i:j}
```

In Python both i and j are evaluated, but in Javascript, only j is evaluated. In Javascript you also have the privilege of writing in the dot notation, using the identifier i. Hence in Python,

```
 i='k'
 j=1
 b = {i:j}
 b['k'] # -> 1
```

In Javascript,

```
 i='k'
 j=1
 b = {i:j}
 b['i'] // -> 1
 b.i // -> 1
 // b[i], b['k'] and b.k are not defined
```

In Javascript, using the identifier in dot notation is completely identical in all cases to using a string that "looks like" the identifier in array notation. Hence, b = { 'i':1 } ; b['i'] // -> 1 b.i // -> 1 When a number or boolean is used in a dictionary, Javascript will access the element using a string representation of the number or boolean. Not so in Python — a string and a number (or boolean) are different hashables.

If you are interested in differences between both languages, then look at [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786522/how-different-are-the-semantics-between-python-and-javascript?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: "In Javascript, a dictionary is the same as an object." In Python, dictionaries are objects too. *Everything* is an object. Javascript *doesn't have dictionaries*, it has objects and maps, the latter being the equivalent of Python dictionaries